# Question involving limit

Tags: real-analysis, limits

How to find the following limit:
$$\lim_\limits{n\to\infty} (ne\sqrt[n]{\ln{(1+e^n)}-n}-n)$$

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what you tried?

Comment: I like this, because while the limit appears to be zero, the expression is too hard for full mathematica.

Comment: +1 for presenting this seemingly complicated limit. In reality it is solved by a direct application of standard limits.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The limit is same even if $n$ is a real variable rather than a positive integral variable. And then we switch to symbol $x$ instead of $n$. We have
\begin{align}
L &= \lim_{n \to \infty}\left(ne\sqrt[n]{\log(1 + e^{n}) - n} - n\right)\notag\\
&= \lim_{x \to \infty}\left(ex\{\log(1 + e^{x}) - x\}^{1/x} - x\right)\notag\\
&= \lim_{x \to \infty}\left(ex\{\log(1 + e^{-x})\}^{1/x} - x\right)\notag\\
&= \lim_{x \to \infty}x\left(\exp\left(\frac{\log\log(1 + e^{-x}) + x}{x}\right) - 1\right)\notag\\
&= \lim_{x \to \infty}x\left(\exp\left(\frac{\log\{e^{x}\log(1 + e^{-x})\}}{x}\right) - 1\right)\notag\\
&= \lim_{x \to \infty}x\cdot\dfrac{\exp\left(\dfrac{\log\{e^{x}\log(1 + e^{-x})\}}{x}\right) - 1}{\dfrac{\log\{e^{x}\log(1 + e^{-x})\}}{x}}\cdot \dfrac{\log\{e^{x}\log(1 + e^{-x})\}}{x}\notag\\
&= \lim_{x \to \infty}x\cdot 1\cdot \dfrac{\log\{e^{x}\log(1 + e^{-x})\}}{x}\notag\\
&= \lim_{x \to \infty}\log\{e^{x}\log(1 + e^{-x})\}\notag\\
&= 0\notag
\end{align}
Note that when $x \to \infty$ then $t = e^{-x} \to 0$ and hence $e^{x}\log(1 + e^{-x}) = \dfrac{\log(1 + t)}{t} \to 1$ and therefore $$\log\{e^{x}\log(1 + e^{-x})\} \to 0$$ and we have used this fact in the above evaluation. As usual *most complicated looking limit problems often do not necessitate the use of powerful methods like Taylor's series and L'Hospital's Rule and simpler tools like standard limits suffice*.

Comment: What difference does it make to switch to reals ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust: I should have written differently. I wanted to stress that $n$ being positive integer is not necessary. The result holds even if $n$ is a real variable. Normally when a symbol $n$ is used I prefer to use theorems on sequences to deal with the limit. Updated my post to reflect this.

Answer (score 4):

**Hint**:

$$\ln(1+e^n)-n=n+\ln(e^{-n}+1)-n=e^{-n}-\frac12e^{-2n}+\frac13e^{-3n}-\cdots=e^{-n}\left(1-\frac{e^{-n}}2+\frac{e^{-2n}}3-\cdots\right).$$

Then

$$ne\sqrt[n]{\ln(1+e^n)-n}-n=nee^{-1}\sqrt[n]{1-\frac{e^{-n}}2+\frac{e^{-2n}}3-\cdots}-n\\
=n\left(1-\frac{e^{-n}}{2n}+\frac{e^{-2n}}{3n}-\cdots\right)-n.$$

Comment: That's certainly another way to do it,albeit a more complicated one.

Comment: @Mathemagician1234: more complicated than what ?

Comment: Then my corrected suggestion below.

Comment: @Mathemagician1234: looks like a dead-end. Can you elaborate ?

Comment: I'll do the computation myself when I have time-but it should work.I'll repost the entire question with this as an alternate solution sometime when I have time to play with it.

Answer (score 1):

I will start from a slightly modified limit:
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(e^n \left(n-ne\sqrt[n]{\ln{(1+e^n)}-n}\right) \right)=\frac12
$$
because that will immediately say that 
$$
\lim_{n\to\infty}\left( ne\sqrt[n]{\ln{(1+e^n)}-n}-n \right)=0
$$

So how do we show this?
Start from 
$$
\log(1+e^n) = \log\left( (1+e^{-n} )e^n\right)=\log(1+e^{-n}) + \log(e^n)  =n+\log(1+e^{-n})
$$
Then 
$$
\ln{(1+e^n)}-n= \log(1+e^{-n})
$$
Now use the expansion for small arguments of $\log(1+u)$ and the binomial theorem (both valid becasue $e^{-n}$ will be tiny) to expand 
$(\log(1+e^{-n}))^{1/n}$
to first order:
$$
(\log(1+e^{-n}))^{1/n} \approx \left( e^{-n}-\frac{e^{-2n}}{2} \right)^{1/n}
= e^{-1} \left(1-\frac{e^{-n}}{2}\right)^{1/n} \approx e^{-1} \left( 
1-\frac{1}{n}\frac{e^{-n}}{2} \right) 
$$
So 
$$ ne
\left( (\log(1+e^{-n}))^{1/n} \right) \approx n-\frac{e^{-n}}{2} + O(e^{-2n})
$$ 
and from that follows 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\left(e^n \left(n-ne\sqrt[n]{\ln{(1+e^n)}-n}\right) \right)=\frac12
$$